# querying abstract elements in xpath with python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'd like to make some xpath queries over abstract elements on the [KML schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd) (like `//AbstractFeatureType` on a kml file).

I'm a noob in python and that make the research and trial quite painful, has anybody crossed the path of this beast during their developing hours?

Thanks,

Nico.

Comment: Could you post your current code?  And are you just trying to get the elements with type="kml:AbstractFeatureType"?

Comment: This question is a bit old and in the end I didn't parse KML in my project, so there is no code anymore. But yes, I was trying to get the elements with type "kml:AbstractFeatureType", which means "kml:Placemark", "kml:NetworkLink" for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an attempt using the page you provided.  My code returns a list of elements who have tagtype==attrib.  s is a string with your xml/kml.

```
import lxml.etree as etree
def find(s,attrib,tagtype='*'):
    tree = etree.fromstring(s)
    return tree.xpath(r'.//%s[@*="%s"]'%(tagtype,attrib))
```